# Unable to share folder with everyone on workgroup server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-permissions

I must be blind and missing something very obvious, I hope you guys can help me out.

I need to share a folder on a workgroup server: Everyone should be able to read the content of the share.

What I did was to be as liberal as possible on File Sharing permissions and limited the permissions on NTFS level. For some reason, I get prompted for my credentials when I access the share.

Security is not a concern here and feel free to be extremely insecure in your suggestions.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

And here's the eventlog with the error:

[image]

What do you think is the problem here? Why am I denied access even if I gave everyone the access?

Answer (score 2):

In WorkGroup mode all the local username of the remotes PC that connect to the server must be created locally on that server. (with same password off course)

As when Explorer try to open the remote directory, it send the username/password, thus lead to the error you see.

So if the account *Bob* with password Hello01 access the server, then Bob with password Hello01 must be created on that server, and so on.

Comment: What I observe matches your description, however, is there a reference to this from MS? 

Also, is there a workaround for this? Having all users as a local user is not an option in this case.

Comment: @user2629636 if you cant, enable the guest account on your server, and add **guest** to the share with full right